# Why is child state resolve functions are executed before parent state promises are resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `ui-router` v0.2.13. [This page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1761) states that:

> All resolves on one state will be resolved before moving on to the
>   next state, even if they aren't injected into that child

And more

> All resolves for all the states being entered are triggered and
>   resolvesd before the transition will enter any states (regardless of
>   the resolve being injected somewhere)

However, in my case, child state resolve function is executed before parent's resolve promise is resolved. How is this possible?

Here:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('route1', {
        url: "/route1",
        templateUrl: "route1.html",
        resolve: {
            parent: ["$timeout", "$q", function ($timeout, $q) {
                var d = $q.defer();
                $timeout(function () {
                    d.resolve();
                }, 5000);
                return d.promise;
            }]
        }
    })
    .state('route1.list', {
        url: "/list",
        templateUrl: "route1.list.html",
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
        },
        resolve: {
            child: function () {
                alert("I'm shown before `parent` resolved");
            }
        }
    });
```

If you navigate to `/route1/list` the alert is immediately shown instead of waiting 5 seconds until a parent resolve promise is resolved.

Comment: This question might be easier to answer if you show some code the reproduces the behavior you are describing.

Comment: The functionality is pretty big to add it to plunker or something, I just wanted to confirm that my understanding of quotes is correct, is it?

Comment: Resolve of parents execute before, you may want to show some code :). The second quote only means that the router state will be altered after the resolves success.

Comment: @gilly3 - added example

Comment: @Eloims - added an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All resolves are guaranteed to be resolved before transition is actually performed. But the statements don't point out that resolve functions will be called synchronously. And that's is correct.

According to the `ui-router` [source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/8ce69d9f7c886888ab53eca7e53536f36b428aae/src/resolve.js), invocables are resolved as "parallel" as possible. Only ones dependent on other invocables (either from parents or from current state declaration) will be executed after their dependencies are resolved.

So the only way to make `child` invocable to be invoked after `parent` is resolved is to specify `parent` as dependency of `child` invocable.

```
.state("route1",{
   //..
   resolve: {
        parent: ["$timeout", "$q", function ($timeout, $q) {
            var d = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                d.resolve();
            }, 5000);
            return d.promise;
        }]
    }
 })
 .state("route1.list",{
    //...
    resolve: {
         child: ["parent", function(parent) {
             //will be called only after parent is resolved
         }]
 })
```

Excerpt from the GitHub [resolve.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/8ce69d9f7c886888ab53eca7e53536f36b428aae/src/resolve.js) source code comments:

> Invocables are invoked eagerly as soon as all dependencies are available. 
>       This is true even for dependencies inherited from a `parent` call to `$resolve`.

Comment: This is a great answer.      Note that in ui-router 1.0, resolves will have 3 policy options: "EAGER" (like current resolve behavior), "LAZY", and "JIT".  Lazy resolves are invoked just before the state they are declared on is entered (this is the behavior the question asker assumes).  JIT resolves are not invoked until something else injects them.

Answer (score 2):

So what is actually going on is that since you are not injecting "parent" into the child routes resolved, it will not wait for the parent before trying to resolve child. If you try this:

```
resolve: {
  child: function(parent) {
    alert("Child Resolved!");
  }
}
```

then your child's resolved will be called after the timeout (resolve) of the parent.

I believe what the doc means is that it will wait for all resolved before carrying out the actual transition to the state such as loading the controller and rendering the templates.

In the plunker below (which I mostly borrowed from an old scotch.io example) I played with moving around the dependencies. If the child resolve depends on a parent resolve then the parent promise is resolved before the child. If the child doesn't depend then the child resolves first (even if the timeout length is set to 0).

In all cases though, the parent and child controllers aren't entered, and the views aren't rendered until both the child and parent are both resolved.

http://plnkr.co/edit/EtU03AfgUAlWNsEH0TuU?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, your assumption _I believe what the doc means is that it will wait for all resolved before carrying out the actual transition to the state such as loading the controller and rendering the templates._ is what really can be what the doc says. I think I'd wait a bit more before accepting the answerl, maybe someone will appear who knows for sure. I upvoted your answer.